# Getting GPS Location without google maps

Tags: android

I want to get **gps location** in my android project without using google maps.
I developed an activity which is **run on emulator** *but not get the location on mobile phones*

Comment: can you please show what you have done?

Comment: Show us your effort:)

Answer (score 0):

This code shows how to get latitude and longitude. Hope it helps

---

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context context;

boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
public boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location;

double latitude;
double longitude;

private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1;

protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if(!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {

        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;

            if (isNetworkEnabled) {

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                    if (location != null) {

                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }

            }

            if(isGPSEnabled) {
                if(location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    if(locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                        if(location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}


public void stopUsingGPS() {
    if(locationManager != null) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}

public double getLatitude() {
    if(location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }
    return latitude;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    if(location != null) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    return longitude;
}

public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

public void showSettingsAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    alertDialog.setMessage("Turn on your GPS to find nearby helpers");

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly download this source code , it will help you to get Lattitude and Longitude . :) from these two you can get your location . hope this helps ..

Happy to Help :) 
https://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/

Answer (score 0):

There are two way that you can get current location 
First is using `GPS` native api and Second is using goolge map library   to do that 
First way is

```
// Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Define a listener that responds to location updates
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
  // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
  makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
  };

// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
       locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

To simple get current location by GPS latitude and longitude:

First put in your AndroidManifest.xml:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>`

Then ask user for permission to access fine location:

```
public void fineLocation(Activity activity) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // get location because permission is granted.
        }
    }
}
```

Then get current latitude and longitude:

```
@SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")
public void gpsLoc(Context context) {
   android.location.LocationManager manager = (android.location.LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
   if (manager != null) {
      for (String provider : manager.getAllProviders()) {
         Location location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
         if (location != null) {
            double lat = location.getLatitude();
            double lon = location.getLongitude();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")
public void gpsLoc(Context context) {
android.location.LocationManager manager = (android.location.LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
if (manager != null) {
  for (String provider : manager.getAllProviders()) {
     Location location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
     if (location != null) {
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lon = location.getLongitude();
     }
   }
 }
}
```